# Live radio stuck at buffering : Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using exoplayer : 2.8.0.

Radio Stream Url: http://stream1.ndtv.com:8080/on-ndtv24x7

When I try to play this radio stream, I get `PlayerStateChanged` for Buffering 3 times and then nothing happens. No audio is played.

Following is my code:

```
val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, null, OkHttpDataSourceFactory(okHttpClient, getString(R.string.app_name), null))
        cacheDataSourceFactory = CacheDataSourceFactory(
                DownloadUtil.getCache(context),
                dataSourceFactory,
                CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)

val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(cacheDataSourceFactory)
                                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(episode.url))

val concatenatingMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()
concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource)
player!!.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource)
player!!.seekToDefaultPosition(0)
player!!.playWhenReady = true
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was using OkHttp extension with exoplayer which does not support ICY, ShoutCast live streams. For now I am using `DefaultDataSourceFactory`. Even that has some issues on older versions. There is an open issue for [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3735)